# How can you use ggplot to superimpose many plots of related functions in an automatic way?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a family of functions that are all the same except for one adjustable parameter, and I want to plot all these functions on one set of axes all superimposed on one another.  For instance, this could be sin(n*x), with various values of n, say 1:30, and I don't want to have to type out each command individually -- I figure there should be some way to do it programatically.

```
library(ggplot2)
```

define trig functions as a function of frequency:  sin(x), sin(2x), sin(3x) etc.

```
trigf <- function(i)(function(x)(sin(i*x)))
```

Superimpose two function plots -- this works manually of course

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,pi)), aes(x)) + stat_function(fun=trigf(1)) +  stat_function(fun=trigf(2))
```

now try to generalize -- my idea was to make a list of the stat_functions using `lapply`

```
plotTrigf <- lapply(1:5, function(i)(stat_function(fun=function(x)(sin(i*x))) ))
```

try using the elements of the list manually but it doesn't really work -- only the `i=5` plot is shown and I'm not sure why when that's not what I referenced

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,pi)), aes(x)) +plotTrigf[[1]] + plotTrigf[[2]]
```

I Thought this `Reduce` might handle the 'generalized sum' to add to a `ggplot()` but it doesn't work -- it complains of a non-numeric argument to binary operator

```
Reduce("+", plotTrigf)
```

So I'm kind of stuck both in executing this strategy, or perhaps there's some other way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using version R <3.2? The problem is that you actually need to evaluate your `i` parameter in your `lapply` call. Right now it's being left as a promise and not getting evaulated till you try to plot and at that point `i` has the last value it had in the `lapply` loop which is 5. Use:

```
plotTrigf <- lapply(1:5, function(i) {force(i);stat_function(fun=function(x)(sin(i*x))) })
```

You can't just add `stat_function` calls together, even without `Reduce()` you get the error

```
stat_function(fun=sin)  + stat_function(fun=cos)
# Error in stat_function(fun = sin) + stat_function(fun = cos) : 
#   non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

You need to add them *to* a ggplot object. You can do this with `Reduce()` if you just specify the `init=` parameter

```
Reduce("+", plotTrigf, ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,pi)), aes(x)))
```

And actually the special `+` operator for ggplot objects allows you to add a list of objects so you don't even need the `Reduce` at all (see code for `ggplot2:::add_ggplot`)

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,pi)), aes(x)) + plotTrigf
```

The final result is

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  Yes, I am on version 3.1.2.
I should have realized about the force(i) -- thanks for the reminder.  And the special syntax for the "+" evaluating over a list automatically in the ggplot() sequence is great -- I never would have thought to try something so simple, but I'm glad the programmers thought of that

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `force` in order to make sure the parameter is being evaluated at the right time.  It's a very useful technique and a common source of confusion in loops, you should read about it in Hadley's book http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

To solve your question: you just need to add `force(i)` when defining all the plots, inside the `lapply` function, before making the call to `stat_function`. Then you can use Reduce or any other method to combine them. Here's a way to combine the plots using `lapply` (note that I'm using the `<<-` operator which is discouraged)

```
p <- ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0,pi)), aes(x))
lapply(plotTrigf, function(x) {
  p <<- p + x
  return()
})
```